# How to decrypt and encrypt HTTPS traffic with haproxy?

Tags: ssl, https, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

Okay, so I know that we can either forward HTTPS traffic via haproxy to backend servers intact or have SSL terminated at the proxy server, and let remaining course of the traffic be unencrypted. But is there a way to make haproxy work such that the traffic is decrypted at the server and recrypted before being sent to the backend nodes?

Basically I am getting half the job done with SSL termination, but I want traffic to be encrypted again once it leaves the proxy server.

Is this possible with haproxy on its own? or is there some other tool I could use in combination with haproxy to create and manage HTTPS/SSL sessions with backend servers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it up like this:
Haproxy terminates the SSL then, instead of forwarding the unencrypted traffic to your backend on a HTTP port, try forwarding it to a HTTPS port on the backend and wrap that in a self signed cert.

i.e:

SSL Traffic -> haproxy:443(domain cert) -> backend:443(internal cert)

I have set this up before and it worked fine